# 'AccessKeyId' error output when running aws s3 commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an instance that has IAM role with several permissions. I get the following error when running s3 commands on that instance:

I run the command

```
 aws s3 cp s3://test-ue1/chef-12.3.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm .
```

and get the following output

```
'AccessKeyId'
```

Does anyone know why? or how I can trouble shoot this?

Comment: Is that the entire text of your error? `'AccessKeyId'`?

Comment: yes it is the entire text

Comment: can you run `aws s3 ls`, any outputs?

Comment: Is your access/secret keys properly configured?

Answer (score 7):

When I ran into this situation it was caused by a bad IAM instance profile configuration, specifically the assume role policy. Fixing that fixed the problem.

I don't have the bad policy anymore, but here's one that works:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because I was trying to use a CloudFormation policy on an EC2 instance.

I had to change the principal from `"Service": "cloudformation.amazonaws.com"` to `"Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"`.

The command that was failing was:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-5-171 ~]$ aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/

'AccessKeyId'
```